# Select a dummy column with a dummy value in hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

when i tried to execute the below query from SQL developer i am getting the appropriate result, were as when i try to execute the same from hibernate it is returning a character object with only D as the output.

> SELECT 'Data' as info from dual

what modification should i do in the query to get the information 'Data' while executing through hibernate.

```
String queryStr = "SELECT 'Data' as info from dual";
Query qry = session.createSQLQuery(queryStr);
qry.list();
```

Comment: How are you executing this? can you provide the code part

Comment: @O.D. : have provided the code part.

Comment: try `SELECT d.Data as info from dual d;`

Comment: @Firo : just for example i gave it as 'from dual', but i will in actual scenario i will be doing it as 'select column1,column2,'Data' as info from table;